# Can water buffalo be hypnotized as depicted in Crocodile Dundee (1986)?

Tags: zoology, hypnotism

In the fictional movie [Crocodile Dundee (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_Dundee), the character Mick Dundee is seen ["hypnotizing" a water buffalo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSyhHJsRsd4) with hand movements.

Is this possible in real life?

Comment: While the movie scene maybe be quite notable, it isn't clear that the claim being made is intended to be believed, nor that many people actually believe it. Can we add some references to people who are repeating the claim as true (or even as possibly true)?

Comment: I just want to know whether that's even possible scientifically.

Comment: Sure - but before someone sits down and spends an hour coming up with a definitive answer, with references to Asian buffalo, definitions of hypnosis, and links to experts - we just want to make it isn't just you who thinks it is more than a made-up scene in a movie.

Comment: @digest: We get your curiosity, but it's not what Skeptics.SE is about. Basically, what we're setting out to do here is debunk fraudulent claims, or provide backing for seemingly outrageous but nevertheless true claims. The point with Crocodile Dundee is that *there is no real claim being made*. (Consider, if you will, [the boomerang scene](https://youtu.be/3hEa0HzqDOA?t=49). That antenna, lacking any aerodynamic shaping, wouldn't fly like that. It's make-believe, a bigger-than-life story being told.)

Comment: I think this would be on topic at Psychology and Neuroscience.